# How to disable just OneDrive for Business, but not the personal MySite?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-on-prem, redirect, mysite, onedrive-for-business

AFAIK it is not possible to disable just the document library of the users' MySite. I guess it would be possible to remove the document library with a custom feature and feature stapling, but that would mean problems if at one point I would want to enable OneDrive again.

Right now I'm thinking to just hide all links to OneDrive for Business via CSS/JS as well as have an IIS redirect for the `personal/|username|/documents`. That isn't pretty, but I can re-enable it at any time.

Disabling personal sites globally (i.e. remove the permission) doesn't help because then the newsfeed/following features don't really work.

Comment: If this is on prem, you could always try to apply a super small quota to the my site web app which basically makes it worthless to use, like 100mb. That'd be a little better than trying to hack something into to remove it (which as a SCA, the user could always add back or bypass entirely).

Comment: Right... added the on-prem tag. I like how you said super small quota making it useless with 100MB, isn't that the default value? ;) Yeah I thought about quota as well, but the user experience is wose I believe. Users *think* they can use it, but with a quota of 1MB they can't do anything with it. That's why I like the IIS redirect with a custom error page (not pretty of course).

Comment: But that wouldn't stop them from creating a new document library in their site, like HaHa Block This IT, and use it for storage, working around your IIS redirect.

Comment: Good thinking. This is just a temporary measure because the customer just doesn't want to think about policies right now, but wants Newsfeeds. Site Contents > Create new library still works of course, so policy will be set anyways. Can't be too small because newsfeed content (images etc.) also count against the policy...